# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError while getting field

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have faced a problem while I was reading from GEOSGeometry object. I have used this code

```
        ds = DataSource(shp file path)
lyr = ds[0]
 for feat in lyr:
                    geom_t = feat.geom.transform(wgs84, clone=True)
                    name =feat.get('name')
```

this code works fine for my shape files.but if `name` field contains a utf8 string such as 'تست' it raises this error

```
    DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /views/importdata/
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte. You passed in b'\xc8\xe1\xe6\xc7\xd1 \xc7\xe3\xc7\xe3 \xd1\xd6\xc7' (<class 'bytes'>)

Unicode error hint

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: �����
```

well I find out this is an internal error which is related to gdal or geos wrapper in django. the error comes from this line

`return force_text(string, encoding=self._feat.encoding, strings_only=True)`
in field.py in this directory

```
D:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\field.py in as_string
```

is there any way to find a solution for this problem?
thanks

Comment: `'تست'` is a Unicode string. If you encode it to UTF-8, you get `b'\xd8\xaa\xd8\xb3\xd8\xaa'`

Comment: @PM2Ring so what is the reason of this error?I thought this is the reason.

Comment: I was mostly just pointing out the difference between Unicode and UTF-8. These bytes: `b'\xc8\xe1\xe6\xc7\xd1 \xc7\xe3\xc7\xe3 \xd1\xd6\xc7'` are definitely _not_ UTF-8, but I don't know what encoding they're using. I tried `'cp1256'` (codepage 1256), which doesn't give an error, but it doesn't match the Unicode string you've posted. It decodes to `'بلوار امام رضا'`. Other codepage options are 864 and 720, but they don't look right either, but it's a bit hard for me to tell how bad they are, since I don't read Arabic. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring you know I tested this `feat.encoding` and it returned `utf-8` this is why I said it it `utf-8` the result of `cp1256` is correct but I have no idea how to set it and fix the problem?

Comment: @PM2Ring the codepage 1256 is correct thanks, it is Persian in fact it is just same as Arabic only there are some more characters, I'd be thankful if you please tell me how to manage to set its encoding

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Django, but at least we've identified the encoding, which is half the battle.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks very much I have to find a way to set its encoding in geometries

Answer (score 0):

well for the other people who might face this problem . I had to set `encoding` in datasource definition.

here is the main part

```
ds = DataSource(shp,encoding='cp1256')
```